# split shell script stuck

Tags: bash, macos, shell, csv

I wrote the following script to try and automate my CSV file imports and keep getting stuck at the last function which is the split. the script runs and asks for the $lines input but doesn't finish. I wanted the script to retain the headers of the original file and output to the resulting files.

```
    #!/bin/bash


function get_file() {
  # get file name
  read -e -p "Enter the name of the file   " file #ENTER FILE NAME
}

function file_check() {
  #check for supported filetype

  if [[ $file == *.csv ]]; #VALIDATE CSV FILE
      then  echo $file looks good! Lets go...

  else

      if [[ $file == *.xls ]] || file == *.sxls ]] || [[ $file == *.txt ]]; #CHECK FOR CONVERSION
        then echo You entered: $file, this file needs to be converted to csv!
    fi
  fi
}
#RE-ENTER FILE NAME
function file_validate() {
  while ! [ -e $file ]; do
  echo No such file, Enter a valid file name!
  get_file
done
}

# SHOW FILE DETAILS
function file_detail() {
  csvlstat --count $file
}

function split() {

  read -e -p "Enter the name of the new file   " new
  read -e -p "Enter the number of records for each file   " lines
  tail -n +2 $file | split -l $lines - split_
  for new in split_*
  do
      head -n 1 $file > tmp_file
      cat $new >> tmp_file
      mv -f tmp_file $new
  done

}
```

Comment: You've created a bunch of functions but I don't see where you are actually calling the `split` function to do its work. Please update your Q to show exactly how you are running your code. Good luck.

Comment: You named the function the same as the split command you use in it. I think that was not your goal since you using switch for the split command while your function not need it. So function keep calling itself and will never end.

Comment: @Edvin thx you hit that one on the head... Much appreciated simple oversight in the function name...